# how to get individual classes for each menu list items

Tags: theming, routes

I am theming my website and used the following code to print my main menu.

```
<?php
 $main_menu = variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu');
 $tree = menu_tree($main_menu);
 print render($tree);
?>
```

Now, I need to have individual class name of each list item, so that I can call different background images using css. I would like to have class with name 'menu-497' as shown in screenshot. I couldn't figure out how this is done. Please help. [image]

Old code which used to load individual list class is below. But this code won't load submenu, so I am not using it.

```
<?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
  'links' => $main_menu,
  'attributes' => array(
    'id' => 'topNav',
  ),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need [Menu attribute](https://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes)s module:

> You should use this module when
>
> - You want to "nofollow" certain menu items to sculpt the flow of PageRank through your site
> - You want to give a menu item an ID so you can easily select it using jQuery
> - You want to add additional classes or styles to a menu item

Alternatively, if you don't mind some coding, see [`theme_menu_link()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7). Comments in it's documentation [already shows how to do it](https://api.drupal.org/comment/11474#comment-11474):

> ```
>    function superseven_menu_link(array $variables) {
>      $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $variables['element']['#original_link']['mlid'];
>
>      return theme_menu_link($variables);
>    }
> ```

Comment: Yes, thank you Molot. But I couldn't understand what I have missed in above code, so that I am not getting individual class with number in each list items. I am in a position where, I couldn't change my code. Please help.

Comment: @SureshAlagar You shouldn't really try to add dynamic classes at tpl level, that's the problem (or at least one of them). Also, I can't see which line of code in your question was supposed to generate these classes at all.

Comment: The code which use to generate class (like class='menu-497') for each list item is added in question. But it had a problem that it won't load up sub menu. (old code added in question)
So, I used another code(show in question) to solve my problem. It load sub-menu but it had class name missing for each list items.

Comment: @SureshAlagar please use edit option on your original question - this site is not a support forum. But if your question will be [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/225745), I'll just remove my answer and will avoid your questions until I'll forget it ;) So please don't be a chameleon.

Comment: I am sorry for this. I've modified my question.